# Wordpress ошибка 502

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

учусь верстать на вордпрессе и все было нормально пока после обновления какогото плагина не стала вылезать вот такая ошибка 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu).
На сервере по мимо вордпресса есть еще другие сайты и они работают нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста что можно сделать в вордпресовскую админку войти немогу влогах выходит что то вроде этого

```
2018/02/28 15:01:18 [error] 21239#21239: *55 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 182.121.101.29, server: 139.83.218.234, request: "GET /wordpress/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "139.59.208.234", referrer: "http://139.59.208.234/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php"
```

буду рад любой информации. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен доступ по ftp. Отключайте плагины один за другим, переименовывая папки плагинов с добавлением точки впереди, например, `/wp-content/plugins/.akismet`

Такие папки Wordpress игнорирует, и не подключает находящиеся в них плагины.

Потом, когда установите причину, уберите точки из имен плагинов, и заново их активируйте. Весь функционал восстановится.

Comment: спасибо большое, странно что сам не догадался, а еще вопрос что нужно сделать чтоб теперь этот плагин работал нормально

Comment: Ответить невозможно, не зная, что это за плагин, какую ошибку он выдает, версии WP, php и т.п. Создайте новый вопрос.