# Нет контента при переносе сайта с хостинга на локальный сервер

Tags: wordpress, denwer

Здравствуйте.
Решил перенести рабочий сайт с хостинга на денвер.

Сделал все как надо - в денвере создал папку сайта, скопировал туда контент, скачал БД и импортировал, в вп-конфигу изменил все данные, в БД изменил siteurl на http://localhost/..., но в итоге при переходе по ссылке локального сайта ситуация такая, как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема в неправильном переносе сайта. Описанные вами действия в общем случае неправильны. Почитайте вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: @KAGGDesign вроде решил проблему с БД, теперь сайт отображается коректно, но не могу зайти в админку. Ввожу данные, подтверждаю - страница просто перегружается и все.

Comment: Попробуйте сбросить куки (правой кнопкой на самый левый значок в адресной строке браузера и т.д.) и сессию (закрыть вкладку в браузере)

Comment: @KAGGDesign я нашел проблему, WP Migrate DB  почему то частично обрезал мой файл с БД, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Сделал дамп через дупликатор, все ок почти. Но с авторизацией дальше проблема. Может быть через то, что у меня стоит авторизация с гугл кодами?

Comment: Ну выключите этот плагин с гугл кодами

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791991/220220

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо, все фурычит :)

Comment: Если мои ответы по ссылкам полезны, их можно отметить как полезные, нажав на стрелочку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.